# PHP .htaccess exception some of .php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `.htaccess` that the function is to hide `.php` extension and convert `user.php?user=username` to be :

```
http://example.com/hidayurie
```

Now I have a problem, I have file `search.php`. When I run the URL : `http://example.com/search?q=username`. It still detect that search is username whereas I have file `search.php`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?user=$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ user.php?user=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ user.php?user=$1&page=$2

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/home/.*$ index.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

How can I set if .php file, then it will open that php file without extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding some conditions to your rules to prevent the rewrite if the URI points to a file that exists. You should also make sure you have multiviews turned off (this can be anywhere in your htaccess file):

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Then add these conditions before each of these 4 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?user=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?user=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ user.php?user=$1&page=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ user.php?user=$1&page=$2
```

Comment: Hi.. I tried, but when I open http://example.com/search, it still redirect to user page

Comment: @hiDayurie where is the code for adding/removing the php extension?

Comment: @hiDayurie you're .php extension thing needs to go before your user.php rules

Comment: @hiDayurie and you need to change the line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` to `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f` to avoid pathinfo

Answer (score 0):

You need to define search and any other different pages/URLs you wish to rewrite, otherwise yeah it will continue to think it's a user and refer to user.php

Example:

RewriteRule ^search/?$ /search.php

RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /search.php.php?q=$1

Second line would allow you to query your search with a clean url, ex; yoursite.com/search/username/